# invalid XML document ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I got the following error while trying to validate XML in PLSQL

ORA-31154: invalid XML document ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "report_indicators", minimum is 1 LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "sequence", minimum is 1 ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 354

What could this mean, any external link or idea on how to solve this?

Comment: This means that your XML cannot be read/parsed by Oracle. For a better answer and recommendation, please add some code snippets & details that triggers this error. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It means that your XML shall be valid against an XML Schema. And it is not. You need to compare XML and its XML Schema.